# How to use NumPy array operations and library functions exclusively to solve array operation without any loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

A function that takes a NumPy array (of any shape and size), and two clipping values, call range_min and range_max. Any values in the input greater than range_max should be clipped to be equal to range_max, and any values less than range_min should be clipped to be equal to range_min. The next cell has the function signature and Python doc code to get you started.

I have implemented different code for this problem but don't know how to do it without loop.

```
import numpy as np
def clip_array_range(list_values):
    for (i, item) in enumerate(list_values):
        if item < -10:
            list_values[i]= -10
        elif item > 10:
            list_values[i]= 10
    return list_values   

print(clip_array_range([-3, 2, 3, 5, 22, -12, -8, 2, 10, 38, 15]))
# expected result: [ -3   2   3   5  10 -10  -8   2  10  10  10]

print(clip_array_range([100, -100,50, -50]))
new = np.reshape(clip_array_range, (-1))# I have tried change 1D 
array into 2D as a output but it's not working
print(new)

# expected result:
#[[ 10 -10]
# [ 10 -10]]
```

There is no error in this code but trying to understand different type of logic to do it without loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def clip_array_range(list_values, min_value=-10, max_value=10):
    return np.maximum(min_value, np.minimum(list_values, max_value))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
np.where(a < -10, -10, np.where(a > 10, 10, a))
```